# Table Elements are equal. but still returns error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
var outcomes = {
    "X": 0,
    "O": 1
}
let obj = [
outcomes[game[0].val], outcomes[game[1].val], outcomes[game[2].val],
outcomes[game[3].val], outcomes[game[4].val], outcomes[game[5].val],
outcomes[game[6].val], outcomes[game[7].val], outcomes[game[8].val],
]
console.log(obj[0], obj[1], obj[2])
console.log(obj[0] === obj[1] === obj[2])
```

[Console Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uF59l.png)

It returns
0, 0, 0 on first console.log but returns false when i compare them :\

Answer (score 2):

```
console.log(obj[0] === obj[1] === obj[2])
```

this actually means `true === 0` which is `false`.
change it to:

```
console.log(obj[0] === obj[1], obj[1] === obj[2])
```

then you should get `true true` in the console